# Selecting Highest rows

Tags: sql, ssrs-2012

Please help me with below data. How should I query it.

```
Name        Speed Tier     Usage
Andrew         200          5000
Andrew         100          2000
Luis           100          1000
```

I need to query it in a way that it shows the name which has highest usage. Below is the example

```
Name        Speed Tier     Usage
Andrew         200          5000
Luis           100          1000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.usage = (select max(t2.usage) from t t2 where t2.name = t.name);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just use MAX combined with GROUP BY

```
SELECT Name, Max([Speed Tier]), Max(Usage)
FROM TableName
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY Name
```

Or if you just want the one person with highest value

```
SELECT TOP 1 Name, [Speed Tier], Usage
FROM TableName
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY [Usage] desc
```

Or if you want the highest Usage and what speed it was that current row

```
;with CTE as (SELECT TOP 1 Name, Max(Usage) as Usage
FROM @mytable
GROUP BY Name
Order by Usage desc
)
select 
    T.name, T.[Speed Tier], T.usage
from cte as C
inner join @mytable as T on T.Name = C.name and T.usage = C.Usage
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1 Name
    ,Usage
FROM your TABLE
ORDER BY Usage DESC -- if you want the highest

SELECT TOP X Name
    ,Usage
FROM your TABLE
ORDER BY Usage DESC -- if you want to select the top X rows

SELECT Name
    ,MAX(Usage) Usage 
FROM your TABLE
GROUP BY Name -- if you want to know each Name's highest usage
```

Comment: Do you think if I can use max function. Because, I showed only  an example. I have many rows like this. I need to have Name which has highest usage only

Comment: So you want each name with the highest usage?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it through `MAX` and `GROUP`:

```
SELECT Name, Max(Usage)
FROM YourTableName
GROUP BY Name
```